# Multiple Authors in scrartcl

Tags: titles, koma-script, texmaker

I have the following code in the document portion and I can't seem to get \and to work with it - I'm assuming that it's due to something specific to using this class?

```
\begin{document}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Maketitle
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}               % Remove page numbering on this page

\printtitle                                 % Print the title data as defined above
\vfill
\printauthor                                % Print the author data as defined above
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Begin document
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% End document
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

I tried using `\maketitle` but that just messes up how my document looks so I'm wondering if there is another way to do this?

Full document:

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% LaTeX Template: Titlepage
% This is a title page template which be used for both articles and reports.
%
% Copyright: http://www.howtotex.com/
% Date: April 2011
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Preamble
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt,twoside]{scrartcl}       % KOMA article

\usepackage[a4paper,pdftex]{geometry}                                       % A4paper margins
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{5mm}                                             % Remove 'twosided' indentation
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{5mm}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Definitions (do not change this)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}   % Horizontal rule

\makeatletter                           % Title
\def\printtitle{%                       
    {\centering \@title\par}}
\makeatother                                    

\makeatletter                           % Author
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\centering \large \@author}}               
\makeatother                            

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Metadata (Change this)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{ \normalsize \textsc{Biomechatronics}    % Subtitle of the document
            \\[2.0cm]                                                   % 2cm spacing
            \HRule{0.5pt} \\                                        % Upper rule
            \LARGE \textbf{\uppercase{Exercise vs. Effort}} % Title
            \HRule{2pt} \\ [0.5cm]                              % Lower rule + 0.5cm spacing
            \normalsize \today                                  % Todays date
        }

\author{
        Author 1\\        
        \and
        Author 2\\
}



\begin{document}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Maketitle
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\thispagestyle{empty}               % Remove page numbering on this page

\printtitle                                 % Print the title data as defined above
    \vfill
\printauthor                                % Print the author data as defined above
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Begin document
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% End document
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a *complete* document? Where do `\printtitle` and `\printauthor` come from?

Comment: Thanks I have uploaded the full document. I am using a cover page template, since I've never worked with one before for my own documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a non-standard way to display title and author information.  The standard `scrartcl` stores the authors in `\@author` and prints them out in a `table` environment.  The standard definition of `\and` is designed to provide the approriate command there.  With your `\printauthor` macro you should provide a corresponding definition of `\and` for your set-up.  Most appropriate seems to be to provide some vertical space, e.g. via

```
\renewcommand{\and}{\vspace{1cm}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% LaTeX Template: Titlepage
% This is a title page template which be used for both articles and reports.
%
% Copyright: http://www.howtotex.com/
% Date: April 2011
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Preamble
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt,twoside]{scrartcl}       % KOMA article

\usepackage[a4paper,pdftex]{geometry}                                       % A4paper margins
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{5mm}                                             % Remove 'twosided' indentation
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{5mm}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Definitions (do not change this)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}   % Horizontal rule

\makeatletter                           % Title
\def\printtitle{%                       
    {\centering \@title\par}}
\makeatother                                    

\makeatletter                           % Author
\renewcommand{\and}{\vspace{1cm}}
\def\printauthor{%                  
    {\centering \large \@author}}               
\makeatother                            

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Metadata (Change this)
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{ \normalsize \textsc{Biomechatronics}    % Subtitle of the document
            \\[2.0cm]                                                   % 2cm spacing
            \HRule{0.5pt} \\                                        % Upper rule
            \LARGE \textbf{\uppercase{Exercise vs. Effort}} % Title
            \HRule{2pt} \\ [0.5cm]                              % Lower rule + 0.5cm spacing
            \normalsize \today                                  % Todays date
        }

\author{
        Author 1\\        
        \and
        Author 2\\
}



\begin{document}
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Maketitle
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\thispagestyle{empty}               % Remove page numbering on this page

\printtitle                                 % Print the title data as defined above
    \vfill
\printauthor                                % Print the author data as defined above
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Begin document
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% End document
% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright cool thank you I'm going to use that then.